# Redirect all variations of a subdomain to the parent domain

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect all subdomains that start with a certain prefix to the parent domain. I tried the code below but it's not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blog\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/blog\/" [R=301,L]
```

For example if someone visits http://blog.example.com/1214234 or http://www.blog.example.com/asdfasdfasdf or any variation of the subdomain it always redirects to the parent domain.

Comment: You could also accomplish this in your DNS zone file